# BASH: Search only between delimiters in file without using "cut"

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

I am trying to create a bash script that searches a large file containing network login records and I want to find the wireless hosts used by a specific user. So I can easily find how many times a user logged in with:

```
echo "The user $user exists in the file $target $(cat $target | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | grep "\<$user\>" | wc -l) times"
```

where $user is defined earlier by a `read user` and $target is defined via an argument when executing the file.

For reference, the formatting of the file in question is as follows:

```
<user> pts/0        2014-02-03 12:13 (<ip>)
<user>    pts/1        2014-02-04 23:56 (<ip>.wireless.xxx.xxx)
<user> pts/2        2014-02-04 23:39 (<ip>.wireless.xxx.xxx)
<user> pts/3        2014-02-04 22:09 (<ip>.wireless.xxx.xxx)
<user>  pts/4        2014-02-04 23:59 (<ip>.wireless.xxx.xxx)
```

where I have replaced the username and full ip for privacy reasons. The difference in spacing after user was to account for varying username lengths.

so based off that I can get a very close answer with:

```
echo "$user has used the following wireless hostnames:"
echo "$(grep "wireless" $target | grep "\<$user\>" | cut -d '(' -f 2 | cut -d ')' -f 1 | sort | uniq )"
```

(here we are assuming none of the usernames include "wireless", for now I am only concerned about the main error) If for some reason I wanted to search for the user "2014", for example, this would return all of the ip addresses even though there is no user "2014". Of course this is just a formality since none of the usernames will be only numbers and shouldn't conflict but even if just to learn I'd rather not have this problem.

So what I need to do is when I have `grep "\<user\>"` I need it to somehow search the first field before the delimiter ' ' (space) which corresponds to the username column, without actually cutting (because I still need the ip). Is there a way to specify a region by delimiters for grep to search?

----sample i/o----

```
$ ./search.sh bigData
What username would you like to search for?
<user>
Total lines in <file>: 53984
The user <user> exists in the file <file> 79 times
<user> has used the following wireless hostnames:
<ip>.wireless.xxx.xxx
<ip>.wireless.xxx.xxx
<ip>.wireless.xxx.xxx 
<ip>.wireless.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: Please add sample output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell grep to search at the beginning of the line with a `^`:

```
echo "$user has used the following wireless hostnames:"
echo "$(grep "wireless" $target | grep "^\<$user\>" | cut -d '(' -f 2 | cut -d ')' -f 1 | sort | uniq )"
```

You can use sed to delete everything between the use and the ip-address, but that won't help you with a user called wireless of irele. Just for learning:

```
sed 's/ .*(/(/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **sed** to reformat your input to a simple tabular format and use **awk** to query that data, much like you would do with a database. To list users whose name contain `2014` you can use the filter

```
sed -e 's/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*/|/;s/[()]//g'\
  | awk -F '|' '$1 ~ "2014" {print($1)}'
```

In **awk** you can combine conditions on fields `$1`, `$2`, … or use complex formats to display selected data with `printf` like:

```
sed -e 's/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*/|/;s/[()]//g'\
  | awk -F '|' '$1 ~ "2014" && $2 ~ 'pts/1' {printf("User: %s, date:%s\n", $1 $3)}'
```